# Which is the best way to save data (numbers) in a plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Initially I had an object made of three properties (numbers 0 to 12). NSCoder and related issues made me avoid using an object and now I store three NSNumbers directly instead. I save a NSMutableArray with the three values in this way

```
NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: cardSign, cardNumber, cardColor, nil];
```

I save and check if data are saved

```
NSLog(@"wrote %hhd", [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES]);
```

I try to retrieve the data:

```
NSArray *dataRead = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (dataRead)
    {
        cardSign = [dataRead objectAtIndex:0];
        cardNumber = [dataRead objectAtIndex:1];
        cardColor = [dataRead objectAtIndex:2];
    }
```

Before saving the variable values are correct.
When I try to retrieve the values I get all 0 or (null).
Which is the best way to store three numbers in a plist file and how do I retrieve it?

Comment: You need to elaborate with details. You are creating a valid mutable array and that's all we know right now.

Comment: Please show your saving/loading code!

Comment: The code above works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your objects "cardSign", "cardNumber", and "cardColor", are not actual objects. When storing array contents or NSArray contents to a file all objects must be Apple recognized objects, NSString, NSNumber, etc...

If for instance cardNumber is defined as follows:

```
int cardNumber;
```

Then when "data" is initialized if should be something like (pay only attention to cardNumber)

```
NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: cardSign, [NSNumber numberWithInt:cardNumber], cardColor, nil];
```

This line is taken directly from discussion section of the Apple API description of the "initWithContentsOfFile" call.

"The array representation in the file identified by aPath must contain only property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects). The objects contained by this array are immutable, even if the array is mutable.